# Shorter version for DOM traversing

Tags: jquery, jquery-traversing

I have a click event on a `.child` class. I want to reach the `.productHolder` div from this class. Now I have a really long selector. I was wondering if there is a shorter version for doing this.

**HTML:**

```
<ul class="sm sm-simple">
    <li>
        <a href="#">INTERNET</a>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Prod 1</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#" class="child">Var M</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="child">Var L</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="child">Var XL</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Prod 2</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Var 1</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <div class="productHolder"></div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**JS:**

```
$('.child').on('click', function (event) {
    productHolder = $(event.target).parent().parent().parent().parent().siblings('.productHolder');
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your existing HTML structure, you can use `.closest()` to traverse up to `sm-simple` then `find()` can be used.

```
 productHolder = $(this).closest('.sm-simple').find('.productHolder');
```